# CodeIgniter access model with $$ fails

Tags: php, codeigniter, variable-variables

I have a model called `Treatment` in CodeIgniter.  I want to load and use this model 'dynamically'.  That is, I don't want to have to call it directly by name (I am trying to generalize some code to use whatever model I tell it).

So, I do this:

```
$namespace = 'blah';
$modelName = 'Treatment';
...
$this->load->model($namespace . '/' . $modelName);
$this->model = $this->$$modelName;
```

However, I get an error when accessing the `$this->$$modelName` variable, saying that the variable 'Treatment' is undefined:

```
Undefined variable: Treatment ... Fatal error:  Cannot access empty
property in /mydir/application/controllers/rest/base_rest.php on line
202.
```

Where line `202` is the line where I am using the `$this->$$modelName` variable.

Now, if I changed line `202` to be:

```
$this->model = $this->Treatment;
```

It works fine.

Does anyone know why I can't seem to use the PHP `$$` syntax here?

Comment: Regular: `$this->Treatment`. Variable: `$this->$modelName` ???: `$this->$$modelName`

Comment: `$$` is the [Variable Variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) syntax in `PHP`.  I didn't know there was a different style of that syntax when referencing a Variable Variable in the way I am here (Although, now looking over it, the documentation has this in Example 1 :S).

Comment: Well, yes, it's looking for the variable variable called `$Treatment` to then use its value as object property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because it's not a supported syntax. Try

```
$this->{$modelName}
```

instead. e.g.

```
php > class foo { public $bar = 42; }
php > $x = new foo();
php > $y = 'bar';
php > echo $x->$$y;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bar in php shell code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in php shell code on line 1
php > echo $x->{$y};
42php >
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks @Marc!  I'll accept your answer once SO lets me (~10 minutes from now).